# error in sending <select> value to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Following is my html

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
<select  id="selectQualification">
            <option value="Select Qualification">Select Qualification</option>
                <option value="Bachelor">Bachelor</option>
                <option value="Graduate">Graduate</option>
                <option value="Master">Master</option>
                <option value="PostGraduate">Post Graduate</option>
                <option value="M.Phile">M.Phil</option>
                <option value="Ph.D">Ph.D</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit"/>
```

This is JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
                var personalInfo = new Object();
                personalInfo.name = $("#name").val();
                personalInfo.age=$("#age").val();
                personalInfo.qualification=$("#selectQualification").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitForm","Account")",
                    data: { name: $("#name").val(), fatherName: $("#fatherName").val(), selectQualification: $("#selectQualification").val() },
                    success: function () { alert("a"); }
            });
            });
        });

        </script>
```

And following is controller method

```
public void AcceptPersonalInfo(string name,string fatherName,string qualification) 
        {

        }
```

Problem is that in AcceptPersonalInfo() method, qualification is has null value. Pls help, why this is happening.

Comment: Other attributes i.e. name and father name values are passed successfully. But qualification value is null

Answer (score 2):

Because the value you're sending is `selectQualification` and the value the controller is expecting is `qualification`.

so either change

```
public void AcceptPersonalInfo(string name,string fatherName,string qualification) 
{}
```

to

```
public void AcceptPersonalInfo(string name,string fatherName,string selectQualification) 
{}
```

or change

```
data: { name: $("#name").val(), fatherName: $("#fatherName").val(), selectQualification: $("#selectQualification").val() },
```

to

```
data: { name: $("#name").val(), fatherName: $("#fatherName").val(), qualification: $("#selectQualification").val() },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BindAttribute.Prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.prefix%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) Property.

Eg.:

```
public void AcceptPersonalInfo(string name,string fatherName,
                   [Bind(Prefix = "selectQualification")] string qualification){}
```